# How to make Identity use of MVC instead of razor pages in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

Since asp.net core 2.1 the MVC is not supported as default model with Identity. I want to run Identity with MVC in asp.net core 2.2

Make a long story short. This is a asp.net 4.6.2 site with local db that I want upgrade to asp.net core 2.2 . I thought that this would be simple thing. So wrong I was. So what did I do:

1. Created an new ASP.net core 2.0 project with local Identity
2. Scaffolded the ef context with database first with Scaffold-DbContext
3. Fixed so EF is loaded correctly in Startup.
4. Removed aspnetusers, aspnetuserroles, aspnetuserlogin, aspnetroles models from generated scaffold by the Scaffold-Dbcontext
5. Updated ApplicationDbContext to inherits from IdentityDbContext. ApplicationUser inherits from IdentityUser
6. After I faked that the migration have been applied, I manually added following columns in aspnetusers

6.1 ConcurrencyStamp

6.2 NormalizedUserName

6.3 NormalizedEmail

6.4 Changed name LockoutEnd? to LockoutEnd

The system builds but still I cant get it to use the Account controller. I have followed the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2
without no avail. It seems what I do I can't get it to read the mvc controller even after I scaffolded the Identity.

I think the difference in implementations of Identity in asp.net core 2.X Identity is either to high or to narrow regarding earlier implementations.

Included part of my startup

```
       services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            // services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.AllowAreas = true;
                //options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
                //options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
            });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = $"/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = $"/Account/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Account/AccessDenied";
        });

        // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
        services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    }
```

I want to use MVC with Identity Core 2.2 with an old database from Identity .Net.

So any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're doing exactly, but it sounds like you've scaffolded the Identity Razor Pages into your project. If that's the case, those are going to take precedent over your controller, since it's a more physical route.

All the other code looks good. You're using `AddIdentity` instead of `AddDefaultIdentity` (so the default UI is not included). Assuming you've actually created an `AccountController` and your routing is set up correctly, then it should work, as long as you don't have the default UI physically scaffolded into your project.

Comment: Ok.. This works and I will set this as answer. But the Accountcontroller needs to be in area called Identity to work.. why I don't know, but it seems that its hard coded in latest Identity core

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have done the same thing. The following might help you. First create equivalent **Application** tables for all **AspNet** tables. The MS SQL Server script below will create:

```
dbo.ApplicationRole
dbo.ApplicationRoleClaim
dbo.ApplicationUser
dbo.ApplicationUserClaim
dbo.ApplicationUserLogin
dbo.ApplicationUserRole
dbo.ApplicationUserToken
```

1. Open MS SQL Server Management Studio
2. Select your database
3. Start a new query
4. Run the script below and replace **YOUR_DATABASE** with the name of your database
5. Next you should copy the contents of your soon obsolete **AspNet** tables into the new **Application** tables. In this process you should also handle the change from datatype **nvarchar** to **int** for **UserId** and **RoleId**.

---

```
USE [YOUR_DATABASE]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ApplicationRole]    Script Date: 24-May-21 9:44:46 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationRole](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ApplicationRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ApplicationRoleClaim]    Script Date: 24-May-21 9:44:46 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationRoleClaim](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ClaimValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ApplicationRoleClaims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ApplicationUser]    Script Date: 24-May-21 9:44:46 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUser](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnd] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ApplicationUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ApplicationUserClaim]    Script Date: 24-May-21 9:44:46 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserClaim](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ClaimValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ApplicationUserClaims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ApplicationUserLogin]    Script Date: 24-May-21 9:44:46 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserLogin](
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderDisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ApplicationUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LoginProvider] ASC,
    [ProviderKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ApplicationUserRole]    Script Date: 24-May-21 9:44:46 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserRole](
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ApplicationUserRole] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [RoleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ApplicationUserToken]    Script Date: 24-May-21 9:44:46 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserToken](
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ApplicationUserTokens] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [LoginProvider] ASC,
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationRoleClaim]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationRoleClaims_ApplicationRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ApplicationRole] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationRoleClaim] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationRoleClaims_ApplicationRoles_RoleId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUser]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationUsers_Club] FOREIGN KEY([ClubId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Club] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUser] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationUsers_Club]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserClaim]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationUserClaims_ApplicationUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ApplicationUser] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserClaim] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationUserClaims_ApplicationUsers_UserId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserLogin]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationUserLogins_ApplicationUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ApplicationUser] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserLogin] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationUserLogins_ApplicationUsers_UserId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserRole]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationUserRole_ApplicationRole] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ApplicationRole] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserRole] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationUserRole_ApplicationRole]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserRole]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationUserRole_ApplicationUser] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ApplicationUser] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserRole] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationUserRole_ApplicationUser]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserToken]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationUserTokens_ApplicationUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ApplicationUser] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationUserToken] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationUserTokens_ApplicationUsers_UserId]
GO
```